# Selenium - how to take multiple screenshots (burst) and save them too

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Upon visiting the site containing data I get the "Access Denied" message but thanks to a bug I'm able to see the data I want to scrape for about one tenth of a second.

I don't believe that it would be possible to 'download' the data in a .xml or similar format but I'd be happy to just have a screenshot of it.

In order to achieve that I'd need to write code that would screenshot about 30 times in 3 seconds (between requesting page to open and getting "Access Denied" message).

Is that doable?

No language/browser preference, willing to adapt.

Comment: Just do a webdriver wait for the access denied message, and then fall into a loop that will take a screenshot, sleep for one tenth of a second, and then take another screenshot... for about 5-10 seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

For your task, it will be more helpful to use 
`driver.getPageSource()`
It will get html source as String, so you can save it.
See [webdriver docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--)

Comment: Do you reckon it'll work even if content is visible for one tenth of a second only?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can iterate inside loop with saving each result into list and may luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can take as many screenshots as you need by calling `get_screenshot_as_file()` in a loop. Add a timestamp to the screenshot name using [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) so that the `screenshot` names are distinct.

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("C:\\path\\screenshots\\{}.png".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())))
```